# Google analytics event tracking not working

Tags: google-analytics

I have this code setup to track image downloads throught Google Analytics.

```
<a href="/media/37768/CC20100117m001_thumb_2000.jpg"
    onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('Image', 'Download', 'file.jpg');" 
    class="hi-res track">
Hi-Res</a>
```

But the events don't ever show up in the GA reports.

I thought maybe the the browser was following the link before the javascript was being run but setting href="#" doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: How long has it not been working?  Analytics takes some time to update.

Comment: this html is invalid, your href is missing a closing quote

Comment: Two days now. 

Must be 15 Chars??????

Answer (score 5):

Your browser may be following the link before Analytics can make the call logging the event. Check out this page for Google's solution:
http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527

Comment: Updated link: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=55527

Comment: Also, wondering if there's a more robust way to handle this by receiving a response from the event write to know it went through. That coupled with a timeout would help drive the data loss down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your error is but to find out what it is you can:

- Install firefox
- Click on the link
- Go to Tools | Error Console
- Look at the error

Comment: There are no errors. When I run the code from Firebug it returns true

Comment: You can also use Google Analytics Debugger for chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look correct to me--for one thing, you're using 'pageTracker' to call _trackEvent. In fact, _trackEvent is called by an 'event tracker' object, which is instantiated with _createEventTracker.

There are a couple more steps you haven't mentioned so et's go through them all. (There could be more than one correct way to do this--i'm not sure. So what i can do is compare your code with the steps i follow every time i set up Event Tracking, and which so far, have worked every time.)

1. **Enable 'Event Tracking'**. (Do this in
   your profile.)
2. **Create the 'event tracker' instance** and insert it just after the last line of the pageTracker script. This is usually a single line of code that in your case would look something like this:

   ```
   var ImageTracker = pageTracker._createEventTracker("Image")
   ```
3. **Set up the call to the _trackEvent()
   method in your html**. I think all you
   need to do here is replace
   'pageTracker' in your code with 'ImageTracker' (the
   event tracker instance you created
   in step 2 above).

Comment: This answer is deprecated. Please don't use evenTrackers anymore.

Comment: @EduardoCereto - You have a link or reference or something to back that up that you can include so we're not left at a dead end? Thanks.

Comment: @jmort253 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: no--my answer is not deprecated; *EventTrackers* are deprecated (at least according to ec, above). My answer was valid at the time it was posted. As of the OP date and the date of my Answer above, *Event Trackers were in use*, they were the technique advocated by the GA Team, and there was no publicly announced technology intended to take replace them.

Comment: If I understand correctly, event tracking is not deprecated. Instead, the "old method" is deprecated in favor of a new method of event tracking, but event tracking itself as a whole is not deprecated.

Comment: @jmort253 no, just that my answer was valid at the time it was posted. I am not quite sure what e/c claims took the place of Event Trackers--he hasn't said, just threw up a link.

Comment: Doug - Agreed :)  @EduardoCereto made it sound like event tracking was completely removed, which caused my confusion. Thanks for helping to clear that up.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just meant to say that event Trackers were deprecated. You can still use event Tracking but the API changed slightly. I understand he answer was correct when posted. I just wanted to leave this note for people that might be tempting to use this to first check for more recent documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a lot of problem then I realize it's easy steps and want to share with everyone.
First change your script code, link is https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#quickstart

Second add a button like this.
<>button onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'button3', 'clicked'])">Press<>/button>

Enjoy :)

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason the script code provided by GA under Tracking Info does not work with _gaq.push(['_trackEvent');