# Google analytics disabled?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to track events with Google Analytics, here is the code I use

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClickThrough', 'Website', 'lid' + listingid]);
```

listingid is an integer,

I can see that some values are being sent out to Google Analytics, so I assume the code is working fine, but in google analytics, under contents > events, I don't see any of my events, I searched for ClickThrough, and nothing is returned.

I noticed here:
[Google analytics event tracking not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329566/google-analytics-event-tracking-not-working)

that someone says you need to enable event tracking, I could not find out where I need to go to enable event tracking on Google Analytics. Is it disabled by default and where can I enable it?

Comment: How long did you wait before you looked for the event? It usually takes awhile before they show up.

Comment: I waited 1 Day, plus you can change the day range in Google analytics on top right, which will make it show results for today.

Comment: That's weird. Are page views showing up correctly?

Comment: Yes they do, I still think I should activate custom events somewhere or something, should I not?

Comment: I've never had to do anything like that, so not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it, you got to use the latest tracking code, I was using an older one.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking